# Recursive php function that turns nested array into nested html blocks

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to write a recursive php function that would call a function to generate nested HTML blocks ( not necessarily only DIVs ). So for example, for the following array:

```
$a = array(
    'b' => 'b value',
    'c' => 'c value',
    'd' => array(
        'd1' => array(
            'd12' = 'd12 value'
        ),
        'd2' => 'd2 value'
    ),
    'e' => 'e value'
);
```

and the following function

```
function block( $key ) {
    return '<div>'.$key.'</div>';
}
```

would result into

```
<div>
    key - b
</div>
<div>
    key - c
</div>
<div>
    key - d
    <div>
        key - d1
        <div>
            key - d12
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        key - d2
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    key - e
</div>
```

Comment: You don't seem to use the values anywhere (e.g. 'b value'). Is that on purpose?

Comment: why is this community wiki? it is a valid programming question. you're loosing rep!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Excuse the crude formatting and the very crude way of indenting for you, but it should work as you've formatted above. Notice the use of in_array(...)

**CODE**

```
nestdiv($a);

function nestdiv($array, $depth = 0) {
    $indent_str = str_repeat(" ", $depth);

    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        print "$indent_str<div>\n";
        print "${indent_str}key - $key\n";
        if (is_array($val))
            nestdiv($val, ($depth+1));
        print "$indent_str</div>\n";
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<div>
key - b
</div>
<div>
key - c
</div>
<div>
key - d
    <div>
    key - d1
        <div>
        key - d12
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    key - d2
    </div>
</div>
<div>
key - e
</div>
```

Comment: You could change the firs iterator for str_repeat(' ',$depth)

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($myArray); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function divArray($array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
       echo "<div>";
       echo $key;
       if(is_array($value)){
          divArray($value);
       }
       else{
         echo "$value";
      }
       echo "</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: You're only closing the divs when is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function block($a) {
    $ret = '<div>';
    if(is_array($a)) {
        foreach($a as $k => $v)
            $ret .= block($v); 
    } else {
        $ret .= $a;
    }
    $ret .= '</div>';
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function block($array)
{
    $s = '';
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        $s .= '<div>' . $key ;
        if (is_array($value))
            $s .= block($value);
        else
            $s .= $value;
        $s .= '</div>';
    }
    return $s;
}
echo block($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not take into account the fact that he wants to be able to give the `block()` function as parameter :

```
function toNested($array, $blocFunc) {
    $result = '';

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if is_array($value)
            $nestedElement = toNested($value, $blocFunc);
        else
            $nestedElement = $blocFunc($key)

        $result .= $nestedElement;
    }

    return $result;
}

echo toNested($a, 'block');
```