# How to print content inside an array, which is inside some other arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I´m trying to print the value "Viviana" wich is somewhere inside the profile node, in a Drupal 7 installation. What I want is to print the field content that outputs the user name.

I´ve tried this option, but I´ve got errors: `print $field_nombrecompleto1['und'][0]['value'];`

```
The error was Notice: Undefined variable: field_nombrecompleto1 in /home/liga/public_html/sites/all/themes/liga/templates/user-profile.tpl.php on line 7
```

I´m posting the output (a little shortened) after using print_r().

Thanks for your help!

```
Array
(
    [template_file] => sites/all/themes/liga/templates/user-profile.tpl.php
    [variables] => Array
        (
            [elements] => Array
                (
                    [#pre_render] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => _field_extra_fields_pre_render
                            [1] => field_group_build_pre_render
                        )

                    [#entity_type] => user
                    [#bundle] => user
                    [#groups] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#fieldgroups] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#group_children] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#theme] => user_profile
                    [#account] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [uid] => 78
                            [name] => milne
                            [pass] => U$S$9B.hwxhcWeayArrP8Y/qsNXj9SNMh6z5FaCjAebOq1UrYbQJ/uIR
                            [mail] => example@yahoo.com.ar
                            [theme] => 
                            [signature] => 
                            [signature_format] => 3
                            [created] => 1157654988
                            [access] => 1185380339
                            [login] => 1185380321
                            [status] => 1
                            [timezone] => 
                            [language] => es
                            [picture] => 
                            [init] => example@yahoo.com.ar
                                ...
                                ...
                                ...
                    [#view_mode] => full
                    [#language] => es
                    [#block] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [module] => system
                            [delta] => main
                            [theme] => liga
                            [status] => 1
                            [weight] => -53
                            [region] => content
                            [custom] => 0
                            [visibility] => 0
                            [pages] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [bid] => 2154
                            [cache] => -1
                            [subject] => 
                        )

                    [#weight] => -53
                    [#theme_wrappers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => block
                        )   
                        ...
                        ...
                        ...


                    [profile_alumnos] => Array
                        (
                            [#type] => user_profile_category
                            [#title] => Perfil Alumnos
                            [#prefix] => 
                            [view] => Array
                                (
                                    [profile2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [5] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [field_nombrecompleto1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [#theme] => field
                                                            [#weight] => 0
                                                            [#title] => nombrecompleto1
                                                            [#access] => 1
                                                            [#label_display] => hidden
                                                            [#view_mode] => account
                                                            [#language] => und
                                                            [#field_name] => field_nombrecompleto1
                                                            [#field_type] => text
                                                            [#field_translatable] => 0
                                                            [#entity_type] => profile2
                                                            [#bundle] => alumnos
                                                            [#object] => Profile Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [pid] => 5
                                                                    [type] => alumnos
                                                                    [label] => Perfil Alumnos
                                                                    [uid] => 78
                                                                    [created] => 1358457398
                                                                    [changed] => 1358457398
                                                                    [entityType:protected] => profile2
                                                                    [entityInfo:protected] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [label] => Profile
                                                                            [plural label] => Profiles
                                                                            [description] => Profile2 user profiles.
                                                                            [entity class] => Profile
                                                                            [controller class] => EntityAPIController
                                                                            [base table] => profile
                                                                            [fieldable] => 1
                                                                            ...
                                                                            ...
                                                                            ...

                                                                    [field_nombrecompleto1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [und] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [value] => Viviana
                                                                                            [format] => 
                                                                                            [safe_value] => Viviana
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                    [field_cursobasico1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [field_telefonos1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [field_zona1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [entity_view_prepared] => 1
                                                                )

                                                            [#items] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [value] => Viviana
                                                                            [format] => 
                                                                            [safe_value] => Viviana
                                                                        )

                                                                )
                                                                ...
                                                                ...
```

Comment: The error's clear enough: variable `field_nombrecompleto1` doesn't exist. Are you sure you're print_r'ing the right variable?

Comment: yes, that´s why I don´t understand...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive php function that turns nested array into nested html blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766995/recursive-php-function-that-turns-nested-array-into-nested-html-blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your output, you should try:

```
print $your_var['variables']['elements']['profile_alumnos']['view']['profile2'][5]['field_nombrecompleto1']['#object']->field_nombrecompleto1['und'][0]['value'];
```

Where `$your_var` is the variable you used for the `print_r`.

Comment: Thanks! It printed out the output that I wanted!!!    Why should I use the same var that I use with print_r?

Comment: Its not so much that you should, it was the only information I had about the structure of your data. You can make a reference to any variable thats in the path you're interested in, and then reference from there. It all depends on how you intend to treat this data, and which parts you will need to access.

Comment: For example, you could do `$field_nombrecompleto1 = $your_var['variables']['elements']['profile_alumnos']['view']['profile2'][5]['field_nombrecompleto1']['#object']->field_nombrecompleto1;` and then `print $field_nombrecompleto1['und'][0]['value'];` (your original code) should work.

Comment: I see!! Thanks! (I think) I understand now how to print that information! Again, many thanks Martín!