# Finding Array/Object sequence in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, sequence

I have the following array as input:

```
$test = array(
            array(
                'cat','d'=>'fox',
            ),
            'x' => array(
                'y'=> array('fox'),
            ),
        );
```

I need to find the sequence to the value "fox" in this array. Is there any function that would generate the sequence if given array as an input. ie. the output should be in the following format

```
$test[0]['d']
$test['x']['y'][0]
```

Comment: Have you tried writing your own recursive function that does this?

Comment: What have you tried? All I see is an array with a standard method to obtain the sequence, no user created function

Comment: You will need recursion, which will check if value is fox or array (to lauch itself), and store all the keys till this current value

Comment: I'm just searching whether there is any php functions that would enable me to generate the sequence. ie. we have print_r to display the entire array. I thought maybe a similar function might be present

Comment: @dainis abols if no function exists I'll write my own code

Comment: You could try something using `array_search` but you would still need to write a recursive function to get the sequence of keys

Comment: @Dary: I'm searching for a function like
find_sequence('fox',$test)
which would print the needed result.

Comment: I think as of now, there is no library functions in php that gives exact sequence of array, although such functions are really useful for developers

Comment: @AshokGj You can look in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766995/recursive-php-function-that-turns-nested-array-into-nested-html-blocks) question ( and the answers ) to get you started.

Comment: Borrow Laravel's array_dot() function (http://laravel.com/api/source-function-array_dot.html#85-109).  The notation is cleaner, and as a bonus you get a result that is actually useful.

Comment: @Dave `array_dot` is recursive, my attempt is iterative, this makes it faster and more scalable. Getting the same results as the laravel function is just a minor change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments, the answer is simple. You just asking if there is any built in PHP function which does this task.

Answer: No there is no built-in function for that, you have write your own. It should lead to an recursive algorithm. (or even iterative, as recursion can always be replaced by iteration).

Here comes a function which will do the job. Note that I've replaced recursion by iteration, in order to tweak the algorithm:

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'cat','d'=>'fox',
    ),
    'x' => array(
        'y'=> array('fox'),
    ),
);

function pathto($value, $array) {
    // init stack
    $stack = array(array($array, 'array'));
    do {
        // get first value from stack
        list ($current_value, $current_path) = array_shift($stack);

        // if current is a scalar value then compare to the input
        if($current_value === $value) {
            echo $current_path . PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }

        // push array childs to stack
        if(is_array($current_value)) {
            foreach($current_value as $k => $v) {
                $k = is_string($k) ? "'$k'" : $k; 
                // push child and path to file
                array_push($stack, array (
                    $v, $current_path . '[' . $k . ']' 
                )); 
            }   
        }   
    } while (!empty($stack));
}

pathto('fox', $a);
```

Output:

```
$test[0]['d']
$test['x']['y'][0]
```